# Syntax confusion with class

Tags: python

This is the given code:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name 
    def greeting(self):
        return "hi, my name is " + self.name
some_person = Person("yeabsira") 
print(some_person.greeting())
```

However, I was expecting the syntax in which the constructor method uses like:

```
class Name:
    def __init__(self,atribute1,atribute2):
        self.atribute1=atribute1
        self.atribute2=atribute2

new_instance=Name("example")
print(new_instance.atribute1)
```

*****expect answer="example"*****
So my question is how "some_person.greeting()" symantic works?

Comment: Well, if they'd printed `some_person.name`, it would have printed the name, not the greeting.

Comment: That's coding towards the future.  It's "information hiding".  In the future, the underlying implementation might be different.  There might not be a "name" field -- it might read it directly from a database each time.  By creating a function, you establish a "contract".  As long as all users follow the contract, they don't need to be exposed to the internals of the class.

Comment: `some_person.greeting()` works like any other function call.  I don't understand the question...

Comment: That's just calling a method and then printing its return value. `name` is a person's name and `greeting()` constructs a fancier greeting from the name. Its valid to `print(some_person.name)` and `print(some_person.greeting())`. They will print different things. Which you use depends on which thing you want printed.

Comment: @TimRoberts: While information hiding *could* be a reason to prefer a method call over an attribute lookup, it's a lot less necessary to do that in advance in Python than in some other OOP programming languages, since `property` lets you turn a user's attribute lookup into a method call behind the scenes. In any case, I'm not sure this question is about design philosophy as much as it is confusion about methods in general.

Answer (score 1):

`some_person.name` returns the value of the person's name, while `some_person.greeting()` returns a greeting with the name, it is just a function defined within the class `Person` and works normally like any other function. You could use `some_person.name` if you only need the name.

However, by using `some_person.greeting()`, you implemented data hiding, which  hides internal object details, and the user (in the future) only needs to access `greeting()` and not the value of `name` itself.